# missing android.jar when I try to run flutter project

Tags: flutter

Hey I try to run a project but it keeps showing that a android.jar is missing. What can I do ?

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G970F in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> File 'C:\Users\adamr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar' specified for property 'androidJar' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with your Android SDK. Try going to Android Studio, Check if you have installed all the required SDK, must times running `flutter doctor -v` will show you that.

If flutter doctor is fine then I recommend that you uninstall the current android SDK and re-install it.

Answer (score 5):

> This issue occurs when your platform SDK have missing `android.jar` file.

Download `android.jar` file of the android version in the path and put into directory of your *platform SDK* from

https://github.com/Sable/android-platforms

It solved my problem in my `Linux`. I am sure it will work on `Windows` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your android sdk is incomplete. Try install it from Android Studio SDK manager. The folder should looks like the following:
/Users/shooding/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/

```
├── android-stubs-src.jar
├── android.jar
├── build.prop
├── data
├── framework.aidl
├── optional
├── package.xml
├── sdk.properties
├── skins
├── source.properties
├── templates
└── uiautomator.jar
```

Comment: For some reason, android.jar is not being built or downloaded when I install the SDK. Is there a way to tell Flutter to build the .jar file when it is missing?